# Processing dictionary keys in sorted order

Tags: python

In the below code snippets:

```
months = {'January': 1, 'February': 2, 'March': 3, 'December': 12}
```

I want to process the keys in sorted order as shown below:

```
for month_names in sorted(months.keys()):  
    print(month_name, end=' ')
```

But I got the below as output:

```
December February January March
```

I had thought the keys being strings will be sorted numerically and was expecting:

```
February, December, January, March
```

My question is why is this code not sorted numerically? I am an absolute python beginner and want to know this behavior please.

Comment: What do you mean by sorting strings numerically? Strings are sorted lexicographically.

Comment: You're confusing keys() and values().  The keys are the string 'January', 'February', etc.  The values are 1, 2, 3, etc.   And when you sort the names of the months alphabetically, December comes first.

Comment: What kind of sort would yield February, December, January, March?

Comment: ...do you think F comes before D in the alphabet? Are you from a country that orders the alphabet that way? I'm having trouble coming up with any explanation for why you would expect the order you expected.

Comment: what is the logic behind your expected sort? Is february the first month and december is the second and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular order you've mentioned is neither sorted alphabetically nor numerically (by month number).

In the dictionary you've constructed, the key is the name of the month, and value is the month number. So in order to sort the dictionary by month number i.e. by value (which is what I think you wanted?) you can do something like this

```py
for month_name, month_num in sorted(dict.items() key = lambda x : x[1]):
    print(month_name, end=' ')
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the output the questioner was expecting either, though.

Comment: updated my answer @user2357112supportsMonica